# Data set not forming correctly with IN and UNION in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, logic, union

Database Schema

[image: Databse Schema]

Problem -

> Find out the models and prices for all the products (of any type)
>   produced by maker B.

My attempts -

```
SELECT b.model, b.price FROM laptop AS b 
WHERE b.model IN ( SELECT model FROM product WHERE maker = 'B')
UNION
SELECT c.model, c.price FROM pc AS c 
WHERE c.model IN ( SELECT model FROM product WHERE maker = 'B')
UNION
SELECT d.model, d.price FROM printer AS d 
WHERE d.model IN ( SELECT model FROM product WHERE maker = 'B')
```

even this is not showing the correct data set with B only -

```
SELECT b.model, b.price FROM laptop AS b 
WHERE b.model IN ( SELECT model FROM product WHERE maker = 'B')
```

Only one result set is coming.

Let me know about the logical error im making with the query.

EDIT -

Output For -

```
SELECT model FROM product WHERE maker = 'B'
```

[image: quer1]

```
SELECT b.model, b.price FROM laptop AS b 
WHERE b.model IN ( SELECT model FROM product WHERE maker = 'B')
```

[image: output]

Query - `SELECT * FROM product WHERE maker = 'B'`

Output -

[image]

Comment: why not try joining the product table with each of the other 3 tables individually then union those results?

Comment: `query1 UNION query2 UNION query3` your query1, query2 and query3 looks exactly same to me

Comment: Reading the question more closely, I'm unsure what you mean by "Only one result set is coming.".

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson output is not what i need, let me add more

Comment: Change the table names in the query from laptop, laptop, laptop to laptop, pc and printer

Comment: @Orangecrush done..now check

Comment: Maybe 1121 model is not there in the table `laptop` or might be present with white characters? Can you put provide the data set for us to work on?

Comment: @swapnesh What type of product is 1121? If it wasn't a laptop, your change to correct table names could have fixed the result.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson let me check and show u the result

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson added the screenshot..one is for PC and another for laptop ..FYI - correct query in screenshots is the desired output

Comment: @swapnesh The complete query with the unions and the correct table names still gives the wrong output? It looks in your example like you're only testing the part of the query selecting laptops and, naturally, only show laptops in your result.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ur absolutely genius ... yes I was really making that foolish mistake :) Please add this in your answer.. i think im not going to make it in mysql if I do these kind of foolish mistakes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.model, b.price FROM laptop AS b 
...
SELECT c.model, c.price FROM laptop AS c 
...
SELECT d.model, d.price FROM laptop AS d
```

You're selecting from laptop 3 times with identical result sets as a result. Then you `UNION` them together which will remove all duplicates.

EDIT: Your sample query;

```
SELECT b.model, b.price FROM laptop AS b 
WHERE b.model IN ( SELECT model FROM product WHERE maker = 'B')
```

will only find laptops, since that's the only table used. 1121 is a PC, so the query won't show it.

Comment: It was by mistake, although the result is not forming correctly

Comment: Please add your comments in answer so that anyone can get the idea about the problem and solution :) ur simply awesome :)